Kyoto is a famous tourist destination/area/site/spot in Japan

(1) Kyoto is a famous tourist destination in Japan.
(2) Kyoto is a famous tourist area in Japan.
(3) Kyoto is a famous tourist site in Japan.
(4) Kyoto is a famous tourist spot in Japan.

These are my English translation of the same Japanese sentence (京都は日本の有名な観光地です).
Which sentence sounds natural to you?
I assume (1) is natural. My intuition tells me (2) sounds unnatural to native speakers of English. I feel that site and spot refer to small areas, so I think (3) and (4) might be wrong.

Hi. All these work fine in English.  I don't know any Japanese however, so I can't say how accurate the translation is.

Thank you, Billy Kerr. Can we say "Egypt is a famous tourist site/spot"?

Kyoto is a place, city, spot, area, district, prefecture, site, destination, town, region, and many more things as well. You can take your pick, according to what meaning you want.  to say.

Kyoto is a city or destination. The others don't work. And Egypt is a country. area, sport, site are for places within cities. Not the cities themselves.

@Kaguyahime - not really. Egypt is a country which is pretty big. Spot and site suggest something generally smaller - although these don't refer to a precise size, they're too small for a whole country.  For a whole country, it would be better to call it a tourist destination.

"Spot" is rather informal. Also, calling a city a "spot" sounds somewhat ironic

(In my American English, at least) "tourist area" sounds wrong, but "touristy area" is correct. It implies that there are too many tourists. "The beach is beautiful, but don't eat lunch there. It's a touristy area, so the food prices are extra high". (This is similar to "tourist trap" that swmcdonnell mentions, which is a business or attraction that charges too much and only caters to tourists, not locals)

I think your analysis is essentially correct.
(1) Sounds the most natural in BrE when talking about a large area with multiple attractions such as a city.
(2) An area would normally be something like a geographic feature, Death Valley or The Black Forrest or part of a town such as Soho or Greenwich Village.
(3) and (4) Usually refer to a specific location. The Pyramids in Egypt are a tourist site whist The Cavern Club in Liverpool could be said to be a spot. Often a spot would offer some sort of entertainment or maybe food.

They are all equally acceptable and natural sounding. #4 is a little more casual than the others, but that's really the only difference between them.
Incidentally, an antonym for these words would be trap (negative connotation).
